# mkpasswd not accepting options documention conflicts with -h

Tags: passwords

Ubuntu 20.04 Jammy
mkpasswd version 5.5.13
mkpasswd documentation:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkpasswd
Yet, if I try mkpasswd -l 20 (as per documentation)
I receive:
mkpasswd: invalid option -- 'l'
Try 'mkpasswd --help' for more information.
then:
mkpasswd --help
Usage: mkpasswd [OPTIONS]... [PASSWORD [SALT]]
Crypts the PASSWORD using crypt(3).

```
  -m, --method=TYPE     select method TYPE
  -5                    like --method=md5crypt
  -S, --salt=SALT       use the specified SALT
  -R, --rounds=NUMBER   use the specified NUMBER of rounds
  -P, --password-fd=NUM read the password from file descriptor NUM
                        instead of /dev/tty
  -s, --stdin           like --password-fd=0
  -h, --help            display this help and exit
  -V, --version         output version information and exit
```

Right now default produces passwords of excessive length:
Like:
mkpasswd

$y$j9T$Je4cWPmmj4udd1aJGKtXf.$y1hdeGItunpxDe3LTqa2Q6J15GnZeaXpiGlUOqs.bf9

Comment: how do you define excessive length?

Comment: Well, I'd like them a bit shorter, say up to 20 characters or less.  Yet I can find no way to input length or really any qualifiers for that matter.

Comment: I think that applies to the password size, not the size of the salted and crypted value it outputs

Comment: By "that" you are refering to what?  Strange the -help has different commands than the mkpasswd documention.  Isn't that strange?

Comment: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mkpasswd.1.html for example does not have `-l`.

Comment: Those helpful hints confict with:  https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkpasswd

Comment: yeah, the die site credits NIST ,but the ubuntu site doesn't.

Comment: SOLVED: pwgen.    

In my personal experience I can't figure out how to reduce mkpasswd results to less than 20 characters in length.  It used to work on previous version of Ubuntu but not apparently on jammy 22.04.  Doesn't seem like a solution is out there.

Answer (score 0):

Your are mixing two completely different programs, not at all related, both called `mkpasswd`

The one whose you linked the man page. Which is an alternative to `pwgen`. It generates password, that you can use for any usage, like pwgen. And have some options. Such as -l to choose the length of the generated password.

The one you are using (which therefore is not the one of the man page), whose purpose is not at all to generate a password. It is a CLI front-end to the `crypt` library. And its purpose is to generate the crypted version of a password. What is stored, for example, it /etc/passwd. So its usage is that you provide the password (which is not generated. Unless you use another program to generate it), and it crypts it, and returns the crypted version.

Comment: Well thank you @chrsig - that really does clear it up.   Why on earth are there two different programs with the same name? I could swear I had used a mkpasswd program in Ubuntu that would take input of length, then return a password of that length.

Comment: If gnu/linux/(rest of ecosystem) was developped by a single company, that would be the strangest and let say it, stupidest decision ever to name two different unrelated programs with the same name. But none of those programs are part of a standard (it is not like ls, grep, awk, etc.). So, well, two different persons wrote two programs, and choose the same name for it. So, these things happen.

Comment: One of the two programs (probably the one distributed by Ubuntu) will become the one associated to the same "mkpasswd", and the other will probably change its name, when the author will want to avoid confusion. Unless they stopped the dev, and don't care anymore. In which case, that mkpasswd will be forgotten. Which is the most probable outcome, since, as you said, pwgen does the same thing and is better known (I never heard of that mkpasswd before trying to understand your problem. Which I've already used pwgen)